# Is there any module for per product gift wrapping in opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

Is there any module available for gift wrapping in opencart? I need per product gift wrapping and the cost should be based on number of product. I need to set the gift wrapping price from admin side. Please suggest some module , which I can customise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use product options for that.  Just add a select or radio option called "Gift Wrapping" and set the price adjustment accordingly.